# Printing an email

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, vsto, office-2010

I am trying to create a VSTO outlook 2010 addin using vs2013 c#.

So far I have a ribbon bar with a button which are appearing on the outlook ribbon.  When I click the button, it simply displays a message box.

How do I get the button to print the selected email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PrintOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861582%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method on the [MailItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332%28v=office.15%29.aspx) object to print out an email.

**Explorer Window Code**

If your ribbon button is displayed in the Outlook Explorer window you can print out all the selected emails using the following code:

```
Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow() as Explorer;
Selection selection = explorer.Selection;

for (int i = 1; i <= selection.Count; i++)
{
    var selectedItem = selection[i];

    if (selectedItem is MailItem)
    {
        MailItem mailItem = selectedItem as MailItem;
        mailItem.PrintOut();
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selectedItem);
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection);
```

**Inspector Window code**

And if your button is displayed in the Inspector window you can print out the email using the following code:

```
Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow() as Inspector;
var currentItem = inspector.CurrentItem;

if (currentItem is MailItem)
{
    MailItem mailItem = currentItem as MailItem;
    mailItem.PrintOut();
}

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(currentItem);
```

**ReleaseComObject**

Also notice I've used the [ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method to release the COM objects. For more information about when to use the [ReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method see [When ReleaseComObject is necessary in Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omars/archive/2004/12/07/276136.aspx?Redirected=true)